# Issues with @Rule and PowerMockRule

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

in one of my test file. Now when I am removing this part of code several test cases starts failing which are in different folders and having no direct relationship with this file.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the below wiki link for more details.

Technically, instead of using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` , you can use `PowerMockRule`as shown in the below example.

So, when you remove `PowerMockRule`, your tests are gonna fail because you will not have `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` in your tests.

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/powermockrule

> **Bootstrapping using a JUnit Rule**
> Feature avaliable since PowerMock 1.4 Since version 1.4
> It's possible to bootstrap PowerMock using a JUnit Rule instead of
> using the PowerMockRunner and the RunWith
> annotation. This allows you to use other JUnit runners while still
> benefiting from PowerMock's functionality. You do this by specifying:

**With `PowerMockRule`**

```
@PrepareForTest(X.class); 
public class MyTest {
     @Rule
     PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
     // Tests goes here
     ... 
}
```

**Without `PowerMockRule`**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(X.class); 
public class MyTest {

     // Tests goes here
     ... 
}
```